# Exception (index 9, lenght9)

Tags: java, android

So in coding a new app I'm running into a out of bounds exception I can't seem to put my finger on. I stopped the app just before this code block and I get no exception. But once it goes into this block i get fatal exception at java lang                  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
Here is my block that's causing the issue i think.

```
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_view);
     listView.setAdapter(new ContactViewAdapter(this, chatApplication.getStores(), new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == motionEvent.getAction()) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);

                TextView displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                CharSequence charSequence = displayName.getText();

                setDisplayName(charSequence.toString());

                Store store = chatApplication.getStores().get(getDisplayName());
                store.setDelegate(contactActivity);

                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_STORE, store.getInstance().getStringIdentifier());

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }));
    // Gives access to ChatApplication for notifying when instances are found
    setContactActivity(this);
}
```

Comment: Provide your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it. Apparently my app was missing some permissions. Thank you for all your help.